# Google Sheets Query needed to select values matching in other column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, textjoin

been trying to solve this query for a while, tried many variations and never was successfull..

I have the following data set..

[image: current]

I am trying to write a =QUERY() to get the output like in the image below..

[image: needed]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:A, IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A1:A), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(LOWER(B1:B), 1, 0)))), B:C, 2, 0))})
```

[image: 0]